# Redownload traded in game via PS store

Tags: ps4

I purchased a game through a retailer, finished the game, then traded the game in, I then tried downloading the game through the PS store around a year later when it was super cheap  and it wouldn't let me download it, can anyone tell me why? Cheers

Comment: Did you buy it again or just try and download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 cases here:

- If you have **bought** the game again on the PS store but it won't let you download it, I suggest contacting [PlayStation Support](https://support.playstation.com) to fix the issue. It's probably rare for players to buy a physical copy of a game, trade it in, and then re-buy on the PS store.
- If you **haven't bought** the game again and are just trying to download it (I'm assuming it is still marked as owned as you used to own it), then you'd need to purchase the game from the PS store before downloading it again.

Comment: Yeah I tried to redownload it as it was like $10, PS store took my cash but the game couldn't be downloaded, I got refunded after I made a complaint but never got an answer as to why I couldn't download it again, is there a way I can delete actual memory or remove games completely from the system so it woudk t register as having been downloaded on to the console?

Comment: Did you delete the game files you installed from the disk before you tried to download it?

Comment: @Diablo I think you'd need to fully delete the game. Perhaps this can help: https://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/how-to-delete-games-on-ps4/

Comment: Cheers, I'll give it a try and see how it goes.